# IE Startup, app loads fast, but delay in page loading

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

**UPDATE:**  Originally thought this was due to IE9 upgrade, but just uninstalled IE9 (back to IE8) and still have the issue.  I also just upgraded back to IE9.

I **think** this could be related to add-ons but I have disabled all my "Currently loaded add-ons" or removed them completely if that option was available.

While on that note, around the same time I upgraded, I also changed Anti-virus (from Trend Micro to Microsoft Security Essentials).  Trend-Micro had a "plug-in" that I could not remove from IE; even after Trend Micro was uninstalled.  I went through the registry and manually removed all Trend Micro entries.  The plug-in no longer appears in the Add-Ons lists...but yes, the issue still occurs.

---

**Original:**

Ever since I upgraded to IE9, there is a *20* second delay between the app loading and the homepage loading.

So, for instance, if I click IE, I must wait 20 seconds for the first page to load.  I can type any url during this time in the address bar, but nothing happens for 20 full seconds.  It's not a showstopper, but certainly a nuisance.  It only happens on one of my computers (the most powerful one, ironically).

I watched the task manager after it loads and notice that iexplore*32.exe comes up twice, but I don't suppose that is the issue.  In the task manager, while IE is "hanging", neither the processor nor the memory fluctuates.  It's like it's waiting on something else to finish so it can load the first page.

The same thing happens in the 64-bit version of IE as well.

So, I'm curious if anyone else has experienced this issue and, if so, how did you fix it?

PC Info:

- Windows 7, 64-Bit
- 12 GB Ram
- Intel Core i7 CPU
- Microsoft Security Essentials (same as other two, working PCs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some free time this week, formatted the hard drive, and reinstalled Windows 7.

After doing so, I upgraded to IE 9 and added all the other software I need.

Even though it was done the hard way, it's fixed now. :P

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem with IE8 on my work machine. After the program loads, and on any new tab or window that I open, the page hangs upwards of 30 seconds before it'll actually start attempting to retrieve any data for the page. This occurs regardless of it being an internet or intranet site. Doesn't happen in Firefox or Chrome, only IE. I always figured it was due to the proxy configuration. Even though there's nothing in the browser proxy settings, the network forces all web traffic through a proxy somehow (not being a part of the team that manages those settings, I haven't dug too deep into lest they give me a stern talking to for attempting to bypass security).

I would suggest checking the proxy settings in IE, doubtful they'd have changed just because of the install/upgrade but it's something to check.

Comment: I assume you mean the options on the "Internet Options"/"Connections" Tab.  I didn't think to look here, but just checked and everything _looks_ ok (e.g. only option available in Network settings listbox is "Broadband Connection" and the *LAN settings* are set to "Automatically Detect Settings".  It was worth a shot, but not proxies listed.

Answer (score 0):

Check your DNS servers? Try switching to OpenDNS or Google DNS servers; it sounds like some kind of network timeout to me.